# How to remove a database server from Utility Explorer

Tags: sql-server

I use the Utility Explorer to monitor some of my databases but I forgot to remove one before retiring the server. Normally, you could just right click and select "Remove Managed Instance" but I can't do that since the server has been wiped from existence. Now it is stuck in my list without any data

Comment: I don't have this set up to test, but what I would try is setting up Profiler to watch Management Studio, and then use the Remove Managed Instance for another server. Then grab the statements and run them for the retired server. Probably all that's needed is a cleanup of records in `msdb.dbo.sysutility_*` system tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently had to drop a defunct instance from a UCP.
Here's how:

```
DECLARE @instance_id int;

SELECT @instance_id = mi.instance_id
FROM msdb.dbo.sysutility_ucp_managed_instances AS mi
WHERE mi.instance_name = 'defunctservrname\instancename';

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_sysutility_ucp_remove_mi @instance_id;
```

Comment: Ah, nice. Found this article which describes the whole procedure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210565%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I was struglling for 2 hours wondering how to remove UCP from my servers and finally I came to below solution.

```
--must run code on new query page for each server 
--below will show all instance in UCP, what important is instance id
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysutility_ucp_managed_instances

--now delete CUP by instance id, if you added 2 nodes into 1 CUP then do this for instance 1 and 2 or other if any!
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_sysutility_ucp_remove_mi 1;

-- delete UCP data
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_sysutility_mi_remove;

--below will delete all jobs and other objects created by UCP for the specified server
[msdb].[dbo].[sp_syscollector_cleanup_collector]

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_sysutility_ucp_remove;
```

be careful, honestly I don't know if there will be side affects for running this code in a production environment, but for me it was my first time I created CUP and I had nothing to lose so it worked fine!

Also sometimes I re-run codes again in different sequences too